# Syntax Highlighting using Curses::UI::TextEditor

Tags: perl, curses

I'm just working on my first Curses-based app in Perl using Curses::UI. I'm wondering if it's possible to colour specific words in the TextEditor (not the entire thing using -fg).
This would be used for syntax highlighting.

Cheers!

Brad

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is *possible*, but would probably require you to extend or subclass [Curses::UI::TextEditor](https://metacpan.org/source/MDXI/Curses-UI-0.9609/lib/Curses/UI/TextEditor.pm). This is because the TextEditor class appears to render its contents line by line.

I did a tiny bit of fiddling with the `draw_text` method of Curses::UI::TextEditor to prove to my self it could be done:

```
sub draw_text(;$)
{
    # ...
    for my $id (0 .. $this->canvasheight - 1)
    {
        my $line_number = sprintf( "%04d", $id );
        $this->{-canvasscr}->attron( A_REVERSE );
        $this->{-canvasscr}->addstr( $line_number );
        $this->{-canvasscr}->attroff( A_REVERSE );
    # ...
```

This places a reverse color block with the current line number on each line. Course, it doesn't place it at the front of the line like I expected, but I only had about 10 minutes to play. You might have better results with a little more time.

So. Possible? Yes. Easy? Maybe not. There's still the issue of tokenizing your editor contents for highlighting.

Comment: Thanks, Brian! I've subclassed and done a bit of "clean" patching to get some nice results. Currently just highlighting subroutine lines to make them easier to spot in larger files. I think you've definitely pointed me in the right direction so I'm accepting this answer.
Thanks again